# AEM forms - when is it worth it?

Tags: adobe, aem

I was just trying to understand about what would be a valid set of project requirements which would warrant investment in AEM forms?

If you just have a few forms to develop - does it make sense to go for AEM forms and not just use a custom solution using HTML / Js , etc to be able to do this?

I'm talking specifically about AEM forms OSGI and not the JEE one (JEE one has BPM features similar to Livecycle).

Answer (score 2):

AEM forms make sense if

- Authors want control on form fields.
- Tracking conversions based on options within the forms (analytics integration is required to get best results)
- Target integration for changing form fields or flow to give customised experience

  - data injection from AEM stack when using form data sources.

Yes, you can pretty much do a lot with just custom forms and some knuckle grease but most of it is built in the AEM forms and give UX flexiblity to the authors.

Of course, like everything else, AEM forms come with their issues but it's down to individual business requirements.